# Bootstrap 3 custom li element with div designing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a customized li element in Bootstrap 3.
What I want is something like it-

[image: 1].

What I have done is-

HTML-

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" id="baal">
        <div style="display: inline;">
            <div class="inline">
                Anything <img id="image_click" src="http://www.neatimage.com/im/lin_logo.gif">
            </div>

            <div class="inline">
                <img id="image_click" src="http://www.neatimage.com/im/lin_logo.gif">
            </div>


            <blockquote>
                <p>angulard it's obviously tremendously helpful to a lot of people - they took the time to search for a solution,</p>
            </blockquote>
            <div>
                More thing
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="inline">
            <div>
                1
            </div>
            <div>
                2
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divider-vertical"></div>

        <div class="inline">
            <div>
                3
            </div>
            <div>
                4
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>        
    <li class="list-group-item">Music</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Videos</li>
</ul>
```

So, the div's HTML is something like-

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="inline">
        <div>
            1
        </div>
        <div>
            2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider-vertical"></div>

    <div class="inline">
        <div>
            3
        </div>
        <div>
            4
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And the CSS is -

```
/*  List Item Styling   */
div.inline
{
    float:left;
}

.divider-vertical
{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
/*  End - List Item Styling */
```

But what I am getting is-

[image: 2]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .clearfix class as follows:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="inline">
        <div>
            1
        </div>
        <div>
            2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider-vertical"></div>

    <div class="inline">
        <div>
            3
        </div>
        <div>
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

css:

```
/*  List Item Styling   */
div.inline, .divider-vertical   
{
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
}

.divider-vertical   
{
    margin: 0 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```