# Bootstrap 3 Customized li item div styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in Bootstrap 3.

I am trying to create a customized list in Bootstrap 3.

What I have done is-

HTML-

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" id="baal">
            <div class="inline" style="width : 10%;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="inline" style="width : 10%;">
                2
            </div>

            <div class="inline nopadding" style="width : 60%">
                <div>
                    name
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div class="inline" style="width : 33%;">
                        31
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline" style="width : 33%;">
                        32
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline" style="width : 33%;">
                        33
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    XXXX
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="inline" style="width : 10%;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="inline" style="width : 10%;">
                5
            </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Music</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Videos</li>
</ul>
```

CSS-

```
div.inline
{
    float:left;
    overflow: auto;
}

li.list-group-item
{
    min-height: 100px;
    vertical-align : center;
}
```

And getting a list like this-

[image]

But I want to have the inner items vertically aligned.

So I want to have a output like it-

[image: 22]

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: The divs are essentially a submenu...why not use that structure?

Comment: It looks like you might be better of using a table

Comment: I don't know how to use structure.

CaN you please give me an example?

Comment: @AbrarJahin you can use the bootstrap grid system (see my answer below) however it will only work with up to 12 records as that is how bootstrap breaks up it's rows. If you need more that that i would use  Paulie_Ds' answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 custom li element with div designing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318845/bootstrap-3-custom-li-element-with-div-designing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lends itself to using a sub-menu rather than divs. See -

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
li.list-group-item {
  min-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: center;
}
.sub li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="baal">
    <ul class="sub">
      <li class="inline">1</li>
      <li class="inline">2</li>
      <li class="inline">
        <p>name</p>
        <p>31</p>
        <p>XXXX</p>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">32</li>
      <li class="inline">33</li>
      <li class="inline">4</li>
      <li class="inline">5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Music</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Videos</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid system, probably worth noting however that this will only work with up to 12 records.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
            Name
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-1">
           1
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-1">
           2
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
           3
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
           4
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
           5
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
           6
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
           7
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
            xxxx
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

produces:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use "vertical-align", you should add "display: table-cell" to the .list-group-item class